# How to add styling to another element when focus on another element (Different levels)?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I have a text field that I am trying to attach focus styling to and when focused, I want the box the expand and then include an "Add" button below the text area.

Both elements are on different levels (due to the existing structure of the code base). But I can't figure out how to hide/display the button when focusing on the text area. Here's an example of what I'm working with:

```
<form class='container'>
   <div class='form-item'>
      <div class='input-container>
         <textarea id='addComment'></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
   <span class='button-wrapper'>
      <button id='addCommentBtn'></button>
   </span>
</form>
```

And here is the CSS/SCSS I've got

```
#addCommentBtn {
    display: none;
}

#addComment {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    margin: 0.5em;
    width: 95%;
}

#addComment:focus {
    height: 10em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#addComment:focus + #addCommentBtn {
    display: block;
}
```

The expansion of the textarea on focus works as intended, but getting the button the change from display:none to display:block won't seem to work (I've tried a few different variations as well such as visibility).

If it comes down to it, I may have to adjust the Vue components, but this is last resort as it would require more tweaks/confirmation from project lead as the components are used in numerous areas and changes would affect those other areas as well.

ALSO: I would prefer not to use JQuery as well.

Comment: While you could use focus-within to get the button to show I don't understand how that would help you as as soon as the user tries to focus on something else (in this case the button) the button will disappear. Could you explain more what is required?

Comment: I'm wanting to have the  button display when the user focuses on the text area..

Comment: Yes,you can do that, but as soon as the user tries to use the button it wont be there.

Comment: So then I may have to the put the focus on the overall form then, rather than the text area?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem. Flex will automatically adjust the height of container based on content.

```js
function toggleButton(showFlag) {
  document.getElementById('addCommentBtn').style.display = showFlag ? "inline" : "none";
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#addCommentBtn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form class='container'>
   <div class='form-item'>
      <div class='input-container'>
         <textarea id='addComment' onfocus="toggleButton(true)" onfocusout="toggleButton(false)"></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
   <span class='button-wrapper'>
      <button id='addCommentBtn'>Add</button>
   </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Wait, how would adding flexbox fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the problem. Updated the answer.

Comment: Beware that if you navigate by keyboards, the button will disappear when you try to focus it.